# How do I return char count for a line being passed to a function

Tags: count, char

My main.c is where the function ReadLine(Line) is called. Here is the code...

```
#include "Definition.h"
#include "ExternalVar.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char Line[MaxLine];  /* one line from the file */


int NChars = 0,  /* number of characters seen so far */
    NWords = 0,  /* number of words seen so far */
    NLines = 0,  /* number of lines seen so far */
    LineLength;  /* length of the current line */

int word_count = 0,
    line_count = 0,
    character_count = 0;

extern int Readline(),CountWord(),CountUpdate();

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  FILE *fp;

  fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
  while(fscanf(fp,"%s",Line) != EOF)
  character_count = Readline(Line);
  printf("character count for this line is : %d  \n",character_count);
    printf("%s\n",Line);
  fclose(fp);      
}
```

Here is the `Readline.c` file my question is how do I make a loop to count the chars per line and return the value back to Main.c

```
#include "Definition.h"
#include "ExternalVar.h"
#include <stdio.h>


int Readline(char *Line) {
  int internal_count = 0;

  for (internal_count = 0; *Line != '\0'; Line++, internal_count++);
return internal_count;
}
```

This is returning the number of words on the line not the number of chars.

Comment: this exactly is returning the number of characters since it's essentially an implementation of `strlen`.

Comment: nope... your example below will count the number of chars until an \0

Comment: If you formatted your code properly you would immediately see one very obvious bug in `main`.